# Strange inequality about $e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $\displaystyle e^{-x}-\left(1-\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}$ (x>0).

Can we say that this difference less than $\displaystyle \frac{x^{2}e^{-x}}{n}$? 
I've tried to use Taylor formula and estimating $\displaystyle \frac{1}{m!} - \frac{1}{n^{m}}\binom{n}{m}$. But don't have any result. Any idea?

Comment: is this true for $n=1$.

Comment: i think it is meant that the bound is asymptotic on $n$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar yes , I want to know asymptotic inequality for sufficient large $n$.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar yes, but it doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$ e^{-x}-(1-x/n)^n = e^{-x}(1-e^{n\log(1-x/n)+x}) \\= e^{-x}(1-e^{-x^2/(2n)+O(1/n^2)})\\= e^{-x}\left(\frac{x^2}{2n} + O(1/n^2)\right).$$ So for any fixed $x$ your inequality holds with room to spare for large enough $n$.

Note that however, this is not uniform. There is no $n$ such that it holds for all $x>0.$ This is because as $x\to \infty, e^{-x} -(1-x/n)^n \sim -(-x)^n.$

Answer (score 4):

For another approach to the inequality, since $1 - y \leqslant e^{-y}$ and $1+y \leqslant e^{y} $ for $0 \leqslant y < 1$ we have for $x < n$,

$$1 - x/n \leqslant e^{-x/n} \implies (1 - x/n)^n \leqslant e^{-x}\\ 1 + x/n \leqslant e^{x/n} \implies (1 + x/n)^n \leqslant e^x$$

and

$$e^{-x} - (1 - x/n)^n = e^{-x}[ 1 - e^{x}(1- x/n)^n] \leqslant e^{-x}[ 1 - (1 +x/n)^n(1 - x/n)^n] = e^{-x}[ 1 - (1 -x^2/n^2)^n] \\ \leqslant\frac{e^{-x}x^2}{n} .$$

The last step is obtained with Bernoulli's inequality.